# Merging repos into monorepo

Tags: git

I have 2 repositories:

```
repo1
repo2
```

I wanted to merge them in monorepo, so I created new repo and copied both of them inside it:

```
mainrepo
    packages
        repo1
        repo2
```

When I browse source of `mainrepo` source on bitbucket, it looks like this:

```
mainrepo
    packages
        repo1 [<generated string here>]
        repo2 [<generated string here>]
```

And I can not see contents of repo1 or repo2. I think that my mistake was not deleting .git folder when copying repo1 and repo2. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove .git folder from each project

```
rm -rf repo1/.git/
rm -rf repo2/.git/
```

after that send the changes to bitbucket again

```
git add . && 
git commit -m "removed .git folder" && 
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to import the two repos and merge their commit history into a new monorepo. Here is a solution that I wrote and use:

- https://github.com/marcuswestin/monorepo-merge

I've also found two other scripts that look like they might work, but I haven't tried them:

- http://choly.ca/post/git-merge-to-monorepo/
- https://github.com/ksindi/monoreaper